# Convert JSON array with same key value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, frontend

I have a array in this form

```
[
        {
            "time": "2017-09-14 02:44 AM",
            "artist": "Sam",
            "message": "message 1",
            "days": 0
        },
         {
            "time": "2017-09-14 02:44 AM",
            "artist": "Jerry",
            "message": "message 2",
            "days": 2
        },
        {
            "time": "2017-09-14 02:44 AM",
            "artist": "Sam",
            "message": "message 3",
            "days": 4
        },
         {
            "time": "2017-09-14 02:49 AM",
            "artist": "Jerry",
            "message": "message 5",
            "days": 2
        },
         {
            "time": "2017-09-14 02:59 AM",
            "artist": "Sam",
            "message": "message 7",
            "days": 10
        },
        {
            "time": "2017-09-14 02:59 AM",
            "artist": "Sam",
            "message": "message 5",
            "days": 10
        },
]
```

and i need output as like this

```
[{
    artist:"Sam",
    data : [
        {message:"message 1" , days: 0},
        {message:"message 3" , days: 4},
        {message:"message 7" , days: 10},
        {message:"message 5" , days: 10}
    ]
},
{
    artist:"Jerry",
    data : [
        {message: "message 2", days: 2},
        {message: "message 5", days: 2}
    ]
}]
```

Any help from you is highly appreciated.

here is the code i have tried,

```
  var obj = {};
    data.map(function(item){
        if(angular.isDefined(obj.artist) && obj.artist === item.artist){
            obj.data.push({message: item.message, days:item.days })
        }else{
            obj.artist = item.artist;
            obj.data = [];
            obj.data.push({message: item.message, days:item.days })
        }
    });
   console.log(obj);
```

But it creates a single JSON object.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Where is the code you tried ?

Comment: I have edited my question. The code may not be helpful to you guys.

Comment: @AKA Helpful or not, SO is not intended to provide full solutions but to guide your solutions into the right direction. So your code is required even so we can help you fix what ever is causing the issue.

Comment: Mhm, crazy. You want an array as output but your `var obj` is an object.

Comment: are you looping this method?

Comment: No i am not looping it. The code is sequential with what it is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hash table for same artist and collect the data with it.

```js
var data = [{ time: "2017-09-14 02:44 AM", artist: "Sam", message: "message 1", days: 0 }, { time: "2017-09-14 02:44 AM", artist: "Jerry", message: "message 2", days: 2 }, { time: "2017-09-14 02:44 AM", artist: "Sam", message: "message 3", days: 4 }, { time: "2017-09-14 02:49 AM", artist: "Jerry", message: "message 5", days: 2 }, { time: "2017-09-14 02:59 AM", artist: "Sam", message: "message 7", days: 10 }, { time: "2017-09-14 02:59 AM", artist: "Sam", message: "message 5", days: 10 }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        if (!hash[a.artist]) {
            hash[a.artist] = { artist: a.artist, data: [] };
            r.push(hash[a.artist]);
        }
        hash[a.artist].data.push({ message: a.message, days: a.days });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, you are really a master in javascript, i must say.

Answer (score 3):

Try this **[`Array#reduce`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwipzL2gwKTWAhXBPI8KHa5KDS8QFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Freduce&usg=AFQjCNHHMuqxJ882tP03jasOvA3-26VV9Q)** function

1. push `created obj` with the new array.
2. Then create the array only with `artist` value.
3. Then apply to check artist value already present in array or not using 
   `Array#indexOf()>0`.
4. is there .just push the other object to exist data array
5. [`Array#index`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=15&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7g4WgwqTWAhVEs48KHaLzAcsQFghqMA4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FindexOf&usg=AFQjCNHztP-Q4U9kbk-xCGldUWK5RWiOcQ) used find the position of the object presented in new array

```js
var arr = [ { "time": "2017-09-14 02:44 AM", "artist": "Sam", "message": "message 1", "days": 0 }, { "time": "2017-09-14 02:44 AM", "artist": "Jerry", "message": "message 2", "days": 2 }, { "time": "2017-09-14 02:44 AM", "artist": "Sam", "message": "message 3", "days": 4 }, { "time": "2017-09-14 02:49 AM", "artist": "Jerry", "message": "message 5", "days": 2 }, { "time": "2017-09-14 02:59 AM", "artist": "Sam", "message": "message 7", "days": 10 }, { "time": "2017-09-14 02:59 AM", "artist": "Sam", "message": "message 5", "days": 10 }, ]


var res = arr.reduce(function(a,b){
var f =a.map(i=> i.artist)
if(f.indexOf(b.artist) > 0){
  a[f.indexOf(b.artist)].data.push({message:b.message,days:b.days})
}else{
a.push({artist:b.artist, data:[{message:b.message,days:b.days}]})
}
return a;
},[])

console.log(res)
```

Comment: `array.includes()` doesn't work in Internet explorer.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Thank you. but internet explorer not supporting many nums of events.not only `array#includes`